# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') in styles.css

Tags: css, angular, angularjs, typescript, typeerror

So, I am trying to add background color change to my navbar when the scrollY goes more than 30px, and it works though. But I'm getting this error on my console as it is not able to add the new classList to the header when it goes over 30px.

This is my .ts file

```
ngOnInit(): void {   
    function scrollHeader(){
      const nav = document.getElementById('header');
      if(window.scrollY >= 30){ 
        nav.classList.add('scroll-header');
      }else{
        nav.classList.remove('scroll-header');
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHeader);
  }
```

this is the style file:

```
.scroll-header{
    background: #242526;
    color: white;
}

.scroll-header .wrapper .logo a{
    color:white;
}
```

This is the HTML File:

```
<nav id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
            <a [routerLink]="'/'">InsuranceBazaar</a>
        </div>
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="menu-btn">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="close-btn">

        <ul class="nav-links">
            <label for="close-btn" class="btn close-btn">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </label>
            
            <li>
....
```

I don't know what the error is, but I guess it is because of ngOnInit(). Please if anyone knows how to solve this error do share the answer.

Comment: it seems there is no `id="header"` element rendered at the moment this code is being executed. could you provide a piece of code where there is a header?

Comment: Sure. I have added the HTML file

Answer (score 0):

Is your function correctly called ?

Maybe you should try without `ngOnInit()`.

Then try to check the scroll with `console.log()`?
Or maybe try more specifically `#header.scroll-header` then your style ...

Comment: actually outside the ngOnInit() function, the windows object can not be called. It throws me error if I add windows.addEventListener() outside the ngOnInit()